# Concatenate Monthy modis data

Tags: nco

I downloaded daily MODIS DATA LEVEL 3 data for a few months from https://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/datasets. The filenames are of the form MCD06COSP_M3_MODIS.A2006001.061.2020181145945 but the files do not contain any time dimension. Hence when I use ncecat to concatenate various files, the date information is missing in the resulting file. I want to know how to add the time information in the combined dataset.

Comment: i tried these commands:     ncecat -u time in*.nc out.nc,
        ncap2 -O -s 'time[time]=array(5844,1,$time)' out.nc out.nc,  
     ncatted -a units,time,o,c,"days since 2006-01-01" out.nc.   the final file doesn'nt contain any variable and its size becomes very small about 40 k.o

Answer (score 0):

Your commands look correct. Good job crafting them. Not sure why it's not working. Possibly the input files are HDF4 format (do they have a `.hdf` suffix?) and your NCO is not HDF4-enabled. Try to download the files in netCDF3 or netCDF4 format and your commands above should work. If that's not what's wrong, then examine the output files in each step of your procedure and identify which step produces the unintended results and then narrow your question. Good luck.